# Pasting multiline value in Screen GNU executes line by line

Tags: python, gnu-screen

I am used to pasting snippets of code in ipython shell to test things out.

When I copy and paste something like this

```py
print("A")
print("B")
print("C")
```

in ipython shell, it makes it 3 line of code and when you press return after that, it executes the command. But when I do this in a screen session, it does not show all 3 lines of statements. Rather it just runs the first statement and skips the other 2 statements.

So pasting the above would directly give me an output of

```py
In [1]: print("A")
A
```

where as outside of screen I would paste it and it would give me this output

```py
In [1]: print("A")
   ...: print("B")
   ...: print("C")
A
B
C
```

but when pasting a function like

```
def foo():
    print("A")
```

shows both the statements.

I suspect this because when a function or a scope is opened in python it expects another line to be inputed so even if you execute the command, it does not run completely giving you prompt to enter more.

I want my screen to not run these commands when i paste them by return character.